# Measure points X and Y from a list to see how close they are to a straight line

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, graphics

I have a list with a collection of points of X and Y, I want to check how much the points act as a straight line. The number of points is not fixed between lists, so I would like to know how to do it in general and not a short list like 5 points.

In addition, the difference between the points is the parameter time. I would like to know if there is command that can display the straight line and the dots on it like manipulation.

Comment: Just a clarification: the structure of the list is: `list = {{X1,Y1},{X2,Y2},....,{Xn,Yn}}` with `X1,...,Xn,Y1,...,Yn` being numbers. Is that right?

Comment: As a measure of how well some points lay on a line, you may use the "residuals", that is the differences between the y values and the y values of the line. As these have a sign, you may calculate the mean square.

Answer (score 2):

```
data = Table[{x, x + RandomReal[{-.8, .8}]}, {x, 0, 20}];
lm = LinearModelFit[data, x, x]

Show[ListPlot@data, Plot[lm[x], {x, 0, 20}, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]